# how can I convert two string to variable

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
let {q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,personalNumber,name} = req.body;
```

and

```
for (let i = 1 ; i < 7 ; i++) {
    await db.answer.create({
        QuestionId:i,
        a:`${q`${i}`}`.includes('a') ? 1 : 0,
        b:`${q`${i}`}`.includes('b') ? 1 : 0,
        c:`${q`${i}`}`.includes('c') ? 1 : 0,
        d:`${q`${i}`}`.includes('d') ? 1 : 0,
        e:`${q`${i}`}`.includes('e') ? 1 : 0,
        f:`${q`${i}`}`.includes('f') ? 1 : 0,
        g:`${q`${i}`}`.includes('g') ? 1 : 0,
        personalNumber
    });
}
```

but It does not work because `` `${q`${i}`}` `` is not a variable and not equal to `q1` and `q2` and ...
how can I convert `` `${q`${i}`}` `` to variable and read the value of it ?

Comment: Try `\`${q[i]}\``

Comment: Are you trying to access `body.q1` by dynamically creating the variable like `variable = 'q' + 1 ` and `const foo = req.body[variable]`?

Comment: Have you tried making a array with `[q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7]` and iterating trough it with a `map` or `foreach` ? like that, you can get the variables easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the strings to access the properties on `req.body`. Adding a number to a string always creates a string so a lot of the excess is unnecessary:

```
a: req.body['q' + i].includes('a') ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the variable and access it from req.body instead of restructuring. (So that you could use `[ ]` notation).

```
for (let i=1 ; i<7 ; i++){
  const variable = `${q`${i}`}`;
  await db.answer.create({
      QuestionId:i,
      a: req.body[variable].includes('a') ? 1 : 0,
      b: req.body[variable].includes('b') ? 1 : 0,
      c: req.body[variable].includes('c') ? 1 : 0,
      d: req.body[variable].includes('d') ? 1 : 0,
      e: req.body[variable].includes('e') ? 1 : 0,
      f: req.body[variable].includes('f') ? 1 : 0,
      g: req.body[variable].includes('g') ? 1 : 0,
      personalNumber
    });
```

}